# unable to test google endpoint using postman

Tags: postman, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I am trying to use Google Cloud Endpoints as a API Gateway. For the same I created the endpoint and deployed it in a Google Run Container. When I call the url on the browser: `https://...` it works. However, when I try to call the same from Postman I get a `400 Bad Request` error. I notice that from Postman when I try using `http://...` instead of https it works.

From this I concluded that perhaps this has something got to do with the SSL certificate. When I checked the certificate on the browser (by clicking on the lock icon), it shows `*.a.run.app` issued by `GTS CA 1O1`.

Then, I tried to add a Certificate in Postman (I am not sure about this). I opened **Settings** and tried to add a certificate by adding: `*.a.run.app` under host, but it did not work. I am not sure if that is the correct way to add a certificate.

Anyone can suggest what is the way to get the endpoint tested in Postman? Thanks

Comment: related read - https://blog.getpostman.com/2017/12/05/set-and-view-ssl-certificates-with-postman/

Comment: Thanks @hydra for your response. But I am unable to understand what I need to do. Strangely, I am able to call the https url from a Javascript using the fetch command.